# Good PCI-e wireless card for Windows7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I've just build a 64-bit Windows 7 PC but am unhappy with the piddly performance of the Linksys USB wireless dingle I've used. What is a good PCIe alternative that will be stronger for the connection and maybe faster. I don't see why my desktop should show a weaker performance on wireless than my laptop when it's sat next to it or even my Palm Pre for that matter.

Any thoughts?

UK based, max around £60ish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the [D-Link DWA-556](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B000V6C718/) available for £45 ?

Comment: Glad to know it helped ;) You can vote up the answer to mark your question as answered :)